# Array to string conversion when i am uploading image

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying last 2 days i am getting same error again and again when i am uploading image

```
public function add_theme(){
        $config = [
            'upload_path' => './uploads/',
            'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png',
        ];

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if($this->form_validation->run('add_theme') && $this->upload->do_upload()){


            $data = $this->upload->data();
            echo '<pre>';
            print_r($data);
            exit;

        }else{
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            echo $error;//$this->create_template();
        }
}
```

Comment: you wouldn't be trying to upload more than one image per chance? can you share an html snippet of your upload field?

Comment: no i am not trying to upload more than one image

Comment: can you post the exact error you are getting as well as the line it references. and an html snippet?

Answer (score 0):

can use

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$this->upload->initialize($config);
```

Comment: no it's not working after using it same error accor